# Exception with route generation for a cloned/duped object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have a following object

```
class BaseProject
  include Mongoid::Document
end
```

Now let's say I want to create a copy of it via `dup/clone`

```
p1 = Project.first
p2 = p1.clone #p1.dup has the same effect
project_path(p1) #works fine generating /projects/87358736587365 path
project_path(p2) #does not work resulting in an error
```

`No route matches {:action=>"my_action", :controller=>"projects", :id=>#Project{}....`

Note that `:id` parameter is the whole `p2` object hash instead of just an `id`

This could be related to mongoid. Both `dup` and `clone` produce the same result. I know `ActiveRecord` version of those differs and `mongoid` redefines those as well

**Update 1**

Turns out only objects with `persisted?` equal to `true` can generate routes since `to_param` in `Journey::Routing` is required to generate a valid route.

The problem I face is that I can't persist an object since it failed a validation. I guess I'll have to fake routes back to `/projects/new` in order to fix this

Comment: Assuming an up to date version of Rails, I'm surprised that you're seeing the same effect with `clone/dup` since they're different in ActiveRecord, namely that `clone` does not assign an `id` to the new object: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-i-clone I'd look to see what mongoid does to those methods.

Comment: In mongoid 3 ```dup``` and ```clone``` are synonyms

Answer (score 0):

Routes can't be generated for objects that were not persisted even if the object was duped/cloned and has a valid `id`